# microsoft.typescript.default.props not found when opening project in vs 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, typescript, visual-studio-2013

When attempting to open a project which uses typescript in vs2012 I get an error stating microsoft.typescript.default.props not found.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One of the members on the team uses vs2013, and that is what was causing the issue...
Looks like it is a known bug, in case anyone is interested in the resolution, I found it here.
https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/801356/typescript-integration-breaks-backwards-compatibility-of-project-files

there are backwards compatibility issues when using a typescript project from vs2013 to vs2012.  It adds an import, microsoft.typscript.default.props. which doesn't exist in vs2012.

I had to add a conditional import statement in the project file to make it work.

```
<Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)\TypeScript\Microsoft.TypeScript.Default.props"
         Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)\TypeScript\Microsoft.TypeScript.Default.props')" />
```